# Posts 2 posts not functioning

Tags: php, wordpress, post, types

I am using the Posts to Post plugin for Wordpress (version: 1.6.3) to link my posts with a custom post type I created. This custom post type consists of 'authors' that can be linked to a post. Yesterday it was functioning as it should but as for today, the overview is generating a list of 'posts' instead of a list of 'authors'.

I am using the following function to generate a list of authors.

```
function my_connection_types() {
    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
        'name' => 'posts_to_auteurs',
        'from' => 'post',
        'to' => 'auteur'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'p2p_init', 'my_connection_types' );
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? I'm dying for help...

Comment: When I try to link a post at this moment, it gives me the following error: `Invalid second parameter.`

Comment: Show us your code for getting the connected posts.

Comment: It's not about the connected posts, it's about the false connected in the backend of the website. For some reason I can now only link 'posts' to 'posts' instead of 'posts' to 'authors'...